# Theano's support for multi-GPU on a local area network

Tags: neural-network, gpu, theano

I wanted to know if theano could be used to train a neural network on a multi-GPU architecture spread across multiple computers on a LAN.

I already know through Theano's documentation that it can support multiple-GPUs on a single computer but I'm wondering how it could extend to LANs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'd lose most of the benefits of GPU processing communicating across a LAN. Poorly written code can cause GPU transfers that slow down processing significantly, even on a single GPU. To get the most from GPUs in a cluster you should look into parallel versions of Gradient Descent such as Hogwild!

https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~brecht/papers/hogwildTR.pdf